# How would I find the max capacity of a certain series of outputs?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm doing some practice problems from Data Structures and Algorithms textbook to improve my Python skills and it asks me to redesign this code:

```
import sys
data = []
for k in range(15):
a= len(data)
b=sys.getsizeof(data)
print('Length: {0:3d}; Size in bytes: {1:4d}'.format(a,b))
data.append(None)
```

Outputs:

```
Length:   0; Size in bytes:   64
Length:   1; Size in bytes:   96
Length:   2; Size in bytes:   96
Length:   3; Size in bytes:   96
Length:   4; Size in bytes:   96
Length:   5; Size in bytes:  128
Length:   6; Size in bytes:  128
Length:   7; Size in bytes:  128
Length:   8; Size in bytes:  128
Length:   9; Size in bytes:  192
Length:  10; Size in bytes:  192
Length:  11; Size in bytes:  192
Length:  12; Size in bytes:  192
Length:  13; Size in bytes:  192
Length:  14; Size in bytes:  192
```

So I would find the max length for the "Size in bytes". For example the max length for 192 would be 14, the max length for 128 would be 8, etc.

My first thought is to iterate through the data list and set the number before the value changes as the max. But my Python is weak and I would like some pointers as to how to solve this problem.

Thank you very much!
Sorry if I made any mistakes. I am new to the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by storing your data in dictionaries and by using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in combination with [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

```
import sys
import itertools as it, operator as op

data = []
for k in range(15):
  d = {}
  d['Length'] = len(data)
  d['Size in bytes'] = sys.getsizeof(data)
  data.append(d)

for k,g in it.groupby(data,key=op.itemgetter('Size in bytes')):
  print(k,max(i['Length'] for i in g))
```

Result:

```
(72, 0)
(104, 4)
(136, 8)
(200, 14)
```

Comment: No worries! Happy coding to you :-)